# How can I test password expiration using BDD for a website?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd

Let say I have a website with authentication username and password and the user has to change password every X months for security reason (so password expire after X months has been change and the user, next time he/she logs in, will be presented with a change password screen). Imagine there is a column LastChangeDate or NextChangeDate in user table.

Suppose it is a valid acceptance test in BDD, I should have something like

```
Given My password has expired
When I sign in 
And I complete the change password form..
Then I can sign in with the new password
```

How should I implement the first "Given" step?
Is creating a function that expire a user's password (for example going to user table and change LastChangeDate/NextChangeDate) a good practise? That would be just for the sake of testing.

I'm using C# and Selenium but I dont think it's (so) relevant. this is more like a question, how to simulate future events in BDD, but cannot find a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is to include as reference the library containing the repository and use the repository directly to change my user record.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby there is a library called timecop, that is used to do things like this. Basically it gives you the ability to travel to different times. This would allow you to implement your Given something like

```
Given "my password has expired" do
  timecop.travel - password_expiration time
  @i = create user
  timecop.travel present
  @i.expired?.should be_true
end
```

(above is pseudocode)

I'd expect there is something similar in the C# landscape.

Anyhow thats just for reference, in your context opening the user record and setting expired to true is just as viable.